# Which jQuery event can I use to avoid input event trigger when click outside the input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input that is searching with AJAX call through the database and display results. Currently, when I focus the input and start typing the results are shown after I finish typing. But right when the results are shown and I click outside the input (when I remove the focus from the input) the `input event` is triggered again. How can I avoid that?

```html
<input name="searchWord" id="searchW0rd" type="text" placeholder="Search for a company..." autocomplete="off">
```

```
$("#searchW0rd").on('input', function(e) {
     clearTimeout(timeoutID);
     const value = e.target.value;
     timeoutID = setTimeout(() => showResult(1), 500);
});
```

I tried with

```
$("#searchW0rd").on('input', function(e) {
    if($(e.target).is("#searchW0rd")) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        const value = e.target.value;
        timeoutID = setTimeout(() => showResult(1), 500);
    }
});
```

but it didn't worked. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

I also have this AJAX setup (if matters)

```
        $(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
                $(".companies").empty();
                $("#companies-pages").empty();
                $("#placeholder-companies").removeClass('d-none');
            });
            $(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
                $("#placeholder-companies").addClass('d-none');
            });
            $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
                $("#placeholder-companies").addClass('d-none');
            });
            showResult(1);
        });
```

and the `showResult()` function is actually the AJAX call that is displaying the results in a div.

Comment: $("#searchW0rd").on('keyup'....

Comment: Can you include some basic HTML in your question too so we can see this as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? The `input` event shouldn't be getting triggered when focus leaves the field.

Comment: @Pellay Still the same.

Comment: `<input type="text" id="test" />` `$('#test').on('input', function() { console.log('triggered'); });` this example shows no event being triggered when the field loses focus.

Comment: The ajax call is a red-herring if you say you're getting an event on blur.   Try recreating the issue in a snippet (without the ajax call) - the minimum amount of code to reproduce the issue (see [mcve]).  The code you've provided does not demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I added the input html in the question. Can this be caused because of `ajaxStart`, `ajaxStop`? I actually don't know if the event is being triggered it just looks like it. Because as you can see I'm showing and hiding specific divs on ajaxStart & ajaxStop and that's what is actually happening right after clicking outside the input. A placeholder div is being shown and then hidden just like while searching.

Comment: **"*I actually don't know if the event is being triggered*"** - then stick a `console.log("input")` inside the `input` event.

Comment: Is your page reloading?  Watch the network tab (and add liberal console.log()s if you don't want to step through in the debugger)

Comment: @freedomn-m Yeah, it's not triggering the event when removing the focus from the input. It's triggering only when end typing. So the problem is in `ajaxStart` & `ajaxStop` divs visibility. What can I do 'bout it? /// My page is not realoding. Why should I use AJAX and reload the page

Comment: There must be some *other* code?  ajaxStart/Stop should only be firing when there's an actual ajax call - check the network tab to see what it is

Comment: As I said the `showResult()` function is actually the AJAX call.

Comment: Some *other* code that calls `showResult()` - or makes another ajax call.   If you add a `return` at the top of `showResut()` (so it doesn't make the ajax call), do you still get the issue?  ie debug to narrow down the exact cause by eliminating possible causes.

Comment: @freedomn-m When I add a `return` at the top of `showResult()` (so it doesn't make the ajax call) it's not showing and hiding the placeholder divs because the ajax call is not made.

Comment: Right, but even when you change the value and then blur (tab out)?     If so, you've narrowed it down to that being the cause.