# Facing some problems with jQuery AJAX call configuration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an AJAX call that is loading data from a database. I have the following AJAX setup

```
$(function () {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $("#placeholder").removeClass('d-none');
    });

    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
        $("#placeholder").addClass('d-none');
    });

});
```

It's working pretty well until I use the input to search by word / letter. The input is using `input` event to be triggered but the problem is the following:

When I write something in the Input, the placeholders appear until it shows the results and then hide, but after that when I click outside the Input (remove the focus from the input), the placeholders appear for milliseconds and hide again (blink)

I've made a lot of test and the conclusion is that it's not happening because of the `input` event. Here is a thread (by me) for this problem.

[Which jQuery event can I use to avoid input event trigger when click outside the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71768076/which-jquery-event-can-i-use-to-avoid-input-event-trigger-when-click-outside-the)

What can cause this behaviour? I really need help.

Comment: Please create a [mre]. (also, this is basically a duplicate of the other question)

Comment: @ChrisG I have no idea how to explain this problem better.

Comment: What I mean by that is to use a stack snippet (the `<>` button in the editor) to include HTML, CSS and JS that reproduces the problem.

Comment: The problem with this (and the other question) is that we can't really help you without seeing it happen.